# jenkins job stuck Loading node environment variables

Tags: jenkins

Some of the jenkins jobs are stuck with the following message
"[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables".

I tried restarting the slave and that fixed the problem and every thing was working fine for few builds but then it stopped working again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's probably the thing Jenkins does after Loading node environment variables that is getting stuck. What is that?

Comment: You could visit /threadDump on your Jenkins instance to see what Jenkins is doing.

Comment: @DavidPärsson I'm trying to check the threadDump but there are so many threads. The stuck node has many executers. Any idea how to spot the one causing the hang?

Comment: @MohamedSamy, that depends on what is going on, but as far as I can remember the hangs I saw was related to waiting for some kind of I/O or resource allocation. Searching for likely keywords is the best advice I can give.

Answer (score 4):

Try renaming the project.

I don't know why this works - I just read that this had [worked for someone else](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=842844), and it worked for me!

Comment: Even renaming the Job didn't work for me , My slave node is Mac Pro machine

Comment: Ashish Musale did you got a solution to your answer?

Comment: I did some tests in my case:
1) If I rename JOB_NAME job - OK.
2) If I clone JOB_NAME to another name - OK.
3) If I set another job as JOB_NAME - OK.
4) If I rename to another name and then back to JOB_NAME - FAIL.
5) If I rename to another name and then clone back to JOB_NAME - FAIL.

Comment: @and1er, in my case, sometimes wiping out the project workspace helped.
It looks this is somehow related to allocating job workspace on MacOS. But this does not help always.

Answer (score 0):

In my case helped to restart Jenkins agent on which the previous "normal" build has executed (probably Jenkins controller assigned builds to the same agent, but the agent had some problems).